# Why reversed() removes thread safety?

Tags: python, thread-safety, cpython, python-internals, gil

A common idiom in CPython to ensure thread safety for iteration is using `tuple()`.

For example - `tuple(dict.items())` is guaranteed to be threadsafe in CPython even if items are removed by a different thread.

This is because the interpreter does not run the eval loop and does not release the GIL while running these C functions. I've tested it, and it works great.

However, `tuple(reversed(dict.items()))` doesn't seem to be threadsafe, and I can't understand why. It's not running any Python function, it isn't explicitly releasing the GIL. Why am I still getting errors if I delete keys from the `dict` while it runs on a different thread?

Comment: `reversed` working on `dict` and related dict views are relatively new, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes) and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue33462) Maybe it's an actual bug.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure a bug is the correct term, as the GIL does not give you this kind of guarantee per-se, and you're technically supposed to use a lock. It is however unexpected, and I wonder why it works the way it does.

Comment: Perhaps *oversight*?

Comment: Definitely, if ou need thread safety on such data structures you should use an explicit lock, even if in a given Python version you can get away with it. Remember this unpredictability in threaded concurrency  is one of the best arguments in favor of modern single-threaded async. Even for the "tuple" constructor, this "thread safety" should be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: @jsbueno ofc it should count as an implementation detail, but then again why does the gil get released?

Comment: I went to check the PR code that implements it, and I have no idea how it ended up being any different from direct iteration. :-) That is why I did not post an actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying the size of a `dict` while iterating over it will always give an error. The reason why `tuple(d.items())` is thread-safe, is because both retrieval of the iterator and iteration happen in the same C function.
`d.items()` creates a `dict_items` object but there's no iterator yet. That's why changes in dictionary size are still reflected:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> view = d.items()
>>> del d['a']
>>> list(view)
[('b', 2)]
```

However once the iterator has been retrieved the dict size [must not change](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Objects/dictobject.c#L3818) anymore:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> iterator = iter(d.items())
>>> del d['a']
>>> list(iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

And this is what happens when using `reversed`: it [creates a reverse *iterator*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Objects/dictobject.c#L4666) of the dict items. It's the iterator part that causes the trouble, because once the iterator has been created, the underlying dict must not change in size:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> r = reversed(d.items())
>>> r  # Note the iterator here.
<dict_reverseitemiterator object at 0x7fb3a4aa24f0>
>>> del d['a']
>>> list(r)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

So in the specific example `tuple(reversed(dict.items()))` an iterator `reversed(dict.items())` of the original dict is created which is then iterated over by `tuple`. This iterator requires however that the dict does  not change in size. It's like `tuple(iter(dict.items()))` just in reverse order.

Regarding the GIL switch, the eval loop runs when it's taking the result of `reversed()`, after creating the iterator, and sending it to `tuple()` for iteration. See the following dissasembly:

```
>>> dis.dis("tuple({}.items())")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple)
              2 BUILD_MAP                0
              4 LOAD_METHOD              1 (items)
              6 CALL_METHOD              0
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("tuple(reversed({}.items()))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (reversed)
              4 BUILD_MAP                0
              6 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
              8 CALL_METHOD              0
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Awesome, so the final point is that the eval loop does run, after creating the iterator. It happens when it's taking the result of `reversed()`, and sending it to `tuple()`.